# Maya Python - delete objects outside specified area

Tags: python, object, maya, area

I feel like this should be a simple thing to do but just can't seem to find the right commands. I have some code that generates a random spread of polyCubes, and I need to delete any that have a greater y-value than 10 and  any that have an x-value less than -7 and greater than +7. Is there any way to do this using Python code?

Edit: Some of the code:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import random
import math

cmds.select(all=True)
cmds.delete()

zzz = 18

def SMGShot():
    holes = []
    x = 1
    y = 1

    xCoordinate = random.uniform(0,5)
    yCoordinate = random.uniform(0,0.5)
    x = (xCoordinate)
    y = (yCoordinate)

    for number in range( zzz ):
        xStep = random.uniform(-1,0)
        yStep = random.uniform(0,1)
        x = (x+xStep)
        y = (y+yStep)

        bulletHole = cmds.polyCube(w = 0.1, d = 0.1, h = 0.1)
        holes.append(bulletHole[0])
        cmds.move(x, y, 0)
SMGShot()
```

These are the cubes generated, I need any that are randomly generated to be over 10 on y and under -7 / over +7 on x to be deleted.

Comment: Added code as an edit to the original question. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any specific reason to generate these undesired polycubes in the first place? If there is no reason to do so, you could just put an 'if'-statement around the last three lines of your SMGShot function to select the ones that you wish to keep.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. My full program is really long (and a bit messy) so I didn't want to upload it all, but what I'm making is a bullet spray generator for a game. The user inputs data such as distance to target and number of bullets fired, and these are used to generate the spread when the bullets hit a wall. (I'm currently using cubes, though I'm going to model and import holes for the final program). Due to the fact that different data can be inputted each time, and the slight random nature of the spread generation, cubes will only sometimes appear off the wall, and sometimes be fine.

Answer (score 0):

mel for starting point

```
SelectAll;
for ($i in `ls -sl`){
    select $i;
    $t = `xform -q -t`;
    if ($t[1]>10||$t[0]<(-7)||$t[0]>7){delete $i;}
}
```